# Changing passive voice into active voice

Tags: grammar

Change the passive into active 
Let us forget the past.
We should forget the past. Is this the answer

Comment: No, that's not right. Basic questions like this would be better asked on [ell.se]. I suggest deleting the question here and asking it there.

Comment: Actually, [a relevant answer exists already](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/41542/5289).

Answer (score 4):

> *Let the past be forgotten.*

or

> *Let the past be forgotten by us.*